# Is there a way to send modules through the message data?

Tags: pact-lang

Question is, in the repl file I can send the `coin` module in the message data, as the repl parse it into the module itself, and it doesn't require a valid json. But when I try to send it through a real message, it must be a valid json, and therefor there is no way of making it like in the repl file, and it has to be like `"coin"`.
There are reading functions for some other types, (`read-decimal read-integer read-keyset read-string`), but I can't find any function that reads a module, or alternatively casts a string to a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, which is not documented as good as I could search, all you have to do in order to send a module is to send it this way in the json file:

```
'fungible: {"refName": {"name": "coin",
                        "namespace": null
                       },
            "refSpec": [
                         {
                           "name": "fungible-v2",
                           "namespace": null
                         }
                       ]
           }
```

And then read it like that:

`(let ((f:module{fungible-v2} (read-msg 'fungible)) ...)`

Cheers! Viva la Kadena!!